# Spring - wrong method called

Tags: java, spring

I am providing the followind defition in my spring config file:

```
<bean id="path" class="java.nio.file.Paths" factory-method="get">
    <constructor-arg>
        <value type="java.lang.String">${limits.path}</value>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

`Paths.get` can be either called with a String parameter or URI parameter. SPring, in the above example resolves it to URI, which is wrong... Any idea why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with a specific index, it might have a problem since it has a varargs in the method signature.

From the oracle [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Paths.html) :

```
get(String first, String... more)
```

Try Something like that :

```
<bean id="path" class="java.nio.file.Paths" factory-method="get">
    <constructor-arg index="0"
                     type="java.lang.String" 
                     value="${limits.path}" />    
</bean>
```

If it doesn't work, try with an empty list :

```
<bean id="path" class="java.nio.file.Paths" factory-method="get">
    <constructor-arg index="0">
        <value type="java.lang.String">${limits.path}</value>  
    </constructor-arg>
    <constructor-arg index="1">
        <list></list>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```